# Java Networking - Client / Server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

My final project for a class is to put together a game, including multiplayer.  So I started trying to figure out java networking, and I'm kind of stuck.

Each of the two game clients needs to be able to send and receive messages to and from the other client.

The way I figured I would handle this is that I have a NetworkServer and NetworkClient objects that runs in their own threads.

I was thinking that I would just start them from my main game application, but I wanted to do some testing first, so I set this project up:

**NetworkClient:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class NetworkClient extends Thread {

    Socket server;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    Timer timer;


    public NetworkClient(String hostname, int port) throws IOException
    {
        server = new Socket(hostname, port);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SendTask(),  0, 1*1000); 
    }

    public void sendData(Integer b) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(b);
    }



    class SendTask extends TimerTask {
        Integer i = new Integer(1);

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Client: Sending Integer: " + i.toString());
            try {
                sendData(i);
                i = new Integer(i.intValue()+1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // run()
    } // class SendTask

}
```

**NetworkServer:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;


public class NetworkServer extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket client;
    private Integer i;
    private ObjectInputStream in;

    public NetworkServer(int port) throws IOException
    {
       serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
       //serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    }

    public void run()
    {
       try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");  
        client = serverSocket.accept();           
        System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

       while(true)
       {

          try
          {
             i = (Integer) in.readObject();
             System.out.println("Server: Received the integer: " + i.toString());
          }
          catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
          {
             System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
             break;
          }
          catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();

             try { client.close();} catch (IOException e1) {}

             break;
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }

}
```

**Network (The thing I'm using to try and test this):**

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Network {

    NetworkClient client;
    NetworkServer server;

    public Network() throws IOException {
        server = new NetworkServer(6066);
        server.start();

        client = new NetworkClient("192.168.1.196", 6066);
        client.start();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       try
       {
          Network n = new Network();
       }catch(IOException e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

I have the timer in there to facilitate sending data from the client to the server, which would normally be done by my game, but since I'm testing I had to have it send somehow.

When I run this where the client and server are talking to each other, I get both the Sent and Received messages.

When I put it on my laptop (and change the IP in NetworkClient to match my desktop, and vice versa on my desktop) and run it in both places, the client on the desktop sends to the server on the laptop, but the client on the laptop does not send to the server on the desktop.

And at some point during the running, I get an exception about that client's connection being reset by peer, though the working client/server connection continue.

So, I guess my question is, Does anyone know why it works in one direction but not bidirectionally?

**FIXED!!**

Edit: Gah, I figured it out.  It had to do with the timing on starting the two servers.

I changed Network to:

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Network {

    NetworkClient client;
    NetworkServer server;

    public Network() throws IOException {
        startServer();

        startClient();
    }

    private void startServer() throws IOException {
        server = new NetworkServer(6066);
        server.start();
    }

    private void startClient(){
        boolean isConnected = false;
        while (!isConnected) {
            try {
                client = new NetworkClient("192.168.1.196", 6066);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
            isConnected = true;
        }
        client.start();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       try
       {
          Network n = new Network();
       }catch(IOException e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Firewall.  Make sure that java.exe has inbound and outbound traffic enabled.  Also, add a rule to your Firewall for port 6066.

Comment: I was pretty sure I had already done this, but I went and checked anyway.  java.exe has firewall permissions for inbound and outbound and port 6066 is open

Comment: I also added the output of the two computers if that helps at all :)